# load sound dynamically in as2 having problem

Tags: audio, load, actionscript-2, playback

I want to load sound placed in sounds folder.
 Code is

```
var my_sound = new Sound();
my_sound.loadSound("sounds/sound1.mp3");

my_sound.onLoad = function(success:boolean){

     if(success){
        my_sound.start();
      }
}
```

This plays sound when flash is open and pressing CTRL+ENTER(Test Movie).

but when we plays the swf it won't play sound.

for this problem i found one solution.

i made off onLoad function. and the Test Movie. Now the opposite things happend.

It dosen't play when press CTRL+ENTER (TestMovie);

but it plays when swf is playing.

Is there any other way of loading sound.

Comment: When you test your SWF, is it on an HTML Page? or are you simply double-clicking on the SWF file?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var my_sound:Sound = new Sound();
my_sound.onLoad = function(success:Boolean)
{
    if (success)
    {
        my_sound.stop();
    } 
};
my_sound.loadSound("sounds/sound1.mp3", true);
```

This will stop the sound as soon as it's loaded.
Whenever you want to start the sound, just call this function:

```
my_sound.start();
```