# Shuffling an array in Actionscript 3 from a specific, offline file path

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mp3, actionscript-2, shuffle

Just as it says in the title.  Here's the script I am currently using

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;

playsong();

//var songs:Array=new Array("part0.mp3","part1.mp3","part2.mp3","part3.mp3","part4.mp3","part5.mp3","part6.mp3","part7.mp3","part8.mp3","part9.mp3","part10.mp3","part11.mp3","part12.mp3","part13.mp3","part14.mp3","part15.mp3","part16.mp3","part17.mp3","part18.mp3","part19.mp3","part20.mp3","part21.mp3","part22.mp3","part23.mp3","part24.mp3","part25.mp3","part26.mp3","part27.mp3","part28.mp3","part29.mp3","part30.mp3","part31.mp3","part32.mp3","part33.mp3","part34.mp3","part35.mp3","part36.mp3","part37.mp3","part38.mp3","part39.mp3","part40.mp3","part41.mp3","part42.mp3","part43.mp3","part44.mp3","part45.mp3","part46.mp3","part47.mp3","part48.mp3","part49.mp3","part50.mp3","part51.mp3","part52.mp3","part53.mp3","part54.mp3","part55.mp3","part56.mp3","part57.mp3","part58.mp3","part59.mp3","part60.mp3","part61.mp3","part62.mp3","part63.mp3","part64.mp3","part65.mp3","part66.mp3","part67.mp3","part68.mp3","part69.mp3","part70.mp3","part71.mp3","part72.mp3","part73.mp3","part74.mp3","part75.mp3","part76.mp3","part77.mp3","part78.mp3","part79.mp3","part80.mp3","part81.mp3","part82.mp3","part83.mp3","part84.mp3","part85.mp3","part86.mp3","part87.mp3","part88.mp3","part89.mp3","part90.mp3","part91.mp3","part92.mp3","part93.mp3","part94.mp3","part95.mp3","part96.mp3","part97.mp3","part98.mp3","part99.mp3","part100.mp3","part101.mp3","part102.mp3","part103.mp3","part104.mp3","part105.mp3","part106.mp3","part107.mp3","part108.mp3","part109.mp3","part110.mp3","part111.mp3","part112.mp3","part113.mp3","part114.mp3","part115.mp3","part116.mp3","part117.mp3","part118.mp3","part119.mp3","part120.mp3","part121.mp3","part122.mp3","part123.mp3","part124.mp3","part125.mp3","part126.mp3");
var sound:Sound;
var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
var randnum:uint;

function playsong()
{
    randnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*127);
    sound=new Sound();
    var songs:String= "part" + randnum + ".mp3";  
    sound.load(new URLRequest("parts/"+songs)); 
    soundChannel=sound.play();
    soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,playrandomsong);
}

function playrandomsong(e:Event)
{
    playsong();
}
```

And it works...but only when in a similar directory to the SWF file I'm saving it as.  I need to work as if the MP3s were in "D:/parts".  Actionscript and flash aren't really my thing, so I apologize for my noobishness, but I ultimately need a SWF file that can shuffle MP3s that are located in a specific directory...so any help at all in making that happen is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you just want to play the swf locally?

If so, you should be able to load local files from another location by changing:

```
sound.load(new URLRequest("parts/"+songs));
```

to

```
sound.load(new URLRequest("file:///D:/path/to/parts/"+songs));
```

Comment: Ack, so this totally works, but I hit a snag.  The application that I was planning to use this for is older and does not support AS3 - only AS2 and older.  Do you know if this is do-able in AS2 as well?  I tried the same code, but it doesn't load any of the imports.

Comment: Yep you can load sounds in AS2. This post may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593928/load-sound-dynamically-in-as2-having-problem

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there is no need to make exactly web-application. It will work localy. So you can make an AIR aplication by ActionScript 3.

Comment: Would you have an example script I would need to do, but with AIR?  I'm googling a lot, but it's all very confusing for me.

Comment: @dezza gave an absolutly right answer:
`sound.load(new URLRequest("file:///D:/parts/"+songs));`
You can use swf without AIR. But you should set in parameters of compilation: "Access local files only".

Comment: Ack, so this totally works, but I hit a snag. The application that I was planning to use this for is older and does not support AS3 - only AS2 and older. Do you know if this is do-able in AS2 as well? I tried the same code, but it doesn't load any of the imports.